# echo php variable between php scripts

Tags: php

I was given a script with different variables that are based on date and time on the top of XHTML Strict page.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$time = new DateTime();
if($time < new DateTime('2011-10-31 18:00')){
    $title="Before Halloween";
    $cb1="2011,10,31,18,0";
}else if
    ...
?>
```

Halfway through the HTML code I have a second PHP script:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
countdown(2011,10,31,18,0);
function countdown($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute)
{
    ...
?>
```

How can I echo `$cb1` from the upper script into the second script so the third line looks something like **countdown(echo $cb1);** and updates automatically based on the upper script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a string you will need to explode (take apart) at the comma, to create 5 variables. To do this you would use:

```
 $cbarray = explode(",",$cb1);
 countdown($cbarray[0],$cbarray[1],$cbarray[2],$cbarray[3],$cbarray[4]);
```

Or something simalar by putting each one in a named variable.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to set $cb1 as a session variable instead so you can access it from anywhere in the file.

Maybe replace:

```
$cb1="2011,10,31,18,0";
```

with

```
$_SESSION['cb1']="2011,10,31,18,0";
```

And then your code in the second script would be: `countdown($_SESSION['cb1']);`

Comment: This basically is the same as the answer Wasim Karani gave. Countdown uses 5 variables and passing one string, SESSION or VARIABLE, with all 5 elements will not work. This is due to it seeing it as only one variable.